# python - Not Equals to Operand not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-3.3

I am trying to make it so when a value is not equals to another value, then it will draw a rectangle. Here is my code.

```
import tkinter
def a():
    c1 = 1
    c2 = 2
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    canvas = tkinter.Canvas(root, width=800, height=600)

    def b():
        if c1 != c2:
            print ("test")
            canvas.create_rectangle(100, 100, 500, 500, fill='blue')
            root.after(10, b)
    root.after(10, b)
a()
```

As you can see, in function `b`, if the variable `c1` does not equal to `c2` (or vice versa) then it should `print` **"test"**. However it is not printing, nor is it even running the draw rectangle code.

However, when I place another dummy `print` statement before the `if`statement, it will print that.

**Therefore I can tell that my Not Equals to operand is not working, can anyone see what is wrong with my code?**

Comment: You need to add `root.mainloop()` to the end of your `a()` method otherwise it will never draw the application. You also forgot to `.pack()` your canvas widget.

Comment: _"when I place another dummy `print` statement before the `if` statement, it will print that."_ Are you sure? If I put a print statement between `def b():` and `if c1 != c2:`, I don't see any output at all. The program simply terminates immediately.

Answer (score 4):

You probably should not have your root Tk object inside a function.  I'm not completely sure how `tkinter` is structured, but moving `root` outside the function is likely a good idea -- Additionally, you need to enter the `tkinter` main loop before any of your `after` calls will execute:

```
import tkinter
root = tkinter.Tk()

def a():
    c1 = 1
    c2 = 2

    canvas = tkinter.Canvas(root, width=800, height=600)
    canvas.pack()

    def b():
        if c1 != c2:
            print ("test")
            canvas.create_rectangle(100, 100, 500, 500, fill='blue')
            root.after(10, b)
    root.after(10, b)
a()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Sorry. Like Chris Johnson said, I was supposed to use B in place of "check".

Comment: Hi there. It does print the dummy statement, however the rectangle does not draw?

Comment: @monkey334 -- See my update.  You've never made the widget visible (using one of tkinter's geometry managers -- e.g. `.grid` or `.pack`).

Comment: Hi! That works flawlessly. However, I don't think my after loop seems to keep looping if the condition ISN'T satisfied. Is there a way to make it keep looping until it's satisfied? E.g once a user enters a number to change c1 and c2?

Answer (score 1):

You don't appear to be executing the `b` function.  You are defining it but not running it.

Show us the code where the dummy print works -- is it inside the `b` definition?  I doubt it.

Answer (score 1):

remove function b

```
import tkinter
def a():
     c1 = 1
     c2 = 2
     root = tkinter.Tk()
     canvas = tkinter.Canvas(root, width=800, height=600)

    if c1 != c2:
        print ("test")
        canvas.create_rectangle(100, 100, 500, 500, fill='blue')
        root.after(10, check)
    root.after(10, check)
a()
```

Comment: but if he removes `b`, his `root.after(10, b)` calls won't work any more.

Answer (score 0):

You define function b() inside function a(), but You don't call it, wht you want to see?

## EDIT:

Yea, I saw your edit and function works, it print test.

Comment: Please see my new edit in the code in regards to Chris Johnson's comment.